# PHP upload with APC in lightppd

Tags: php, file-upload, apc

I'm using APC to make a upload meter. These are the files:

- [Form](http://pastebin.com/vz3TCJK7)
- [Upload Meter](http://pastebin.com/LcQjAJqx)
- [php.ini](http://pastebin.com/31Ldadb8)

The problem I'm having is I'm getting nothing when I do the FETCH. I'm taking a look at the APC INFO panel as I'm making the upload and I see that the key `upload_XXXXX` isn't stored in the cache **until the file is completely uploaded!**

<strike>What am I doing wrong? Do I have something badly configured in php.ini?</strike>

I've read here that [there's a bug having to do with lightppd](http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=13583).

Comment: why would you want to cache 1/2 a file? is half a zip file good for you? or maybe just half an image?

Comment: Half a file? What are you talking about? Im trying to cache the whole file...

Comment: Are you using mod_php, or are you using FastCGI?

Comment: Im using lightppd with fastCGI

Comment: Please stop putting links in pre tags. The URL does not get translated to a link, and thus nobody can click them.

Comment: you are complaining that the file is not cached untill the entire thing has been uploaded... why do you want to cache bits of a file that is not completely uploaded...

Comment: I *think* his problem is that he cannot see the status of the file upload until the entire file has been upload, which makes it impossible to show the progress bar.

Comment: @Dbugger, it is very likely that FastCGI is the cuplrit here.  FastCGI tends not to be invoked until the *entire body of the request* has been sent from the client to the web server.  This means that PHP doesn't run until the entire file has been uploaded, so no progress information is ever available to APC.

Comment: That's exaclty right. What could I do about this?

Comment: @Dbugger: Not much.  This is either part of the FastCGI specification, or an implementation quirk.  You could try other web servers (nginx or Apache come to mind), but I doubt you'll see the behavior change.  Your best bet is going to be something client-side, like @konforce's new answer.  I'll provide an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, APC's file upload progress indicator is either unreliable or not functional under FastCGI.

Your best bet for a upload progress indicator is therefore going to be client-side.

I'm a big fan of [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), an upload widget that supports no less than six backends to provide better functionality than the regular file input type (including the HTML5 File interface in browsers that support it).  You can [use it standalone with a custom widget of your own design](http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php), or you can [use the included fancy jQuery widget](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php).

If you want something a little more oldschool, there's also [good old SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/).

Both of these options will fall back to a normal file input when Javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this isn't a direct answer to your question, but you may want to consider the HTML5 file API with XMLHttpRequest.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.upload.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
// ...
req.open();
// ...
```

There are some examples on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_xmlhttprequest).

The downside is that it is browser dependent. The upside is that it is server independent. But ultimately, this will be the best way to track file uploads.